# Add extra field in response output in DRF 3.0

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following models

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name_of_the_restaurant = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    opening_time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    closing_time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

And

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    favourite_restaurant = models.ManyToManyField(Restaurant,
                                                  blank=True,
                                                  related_name='favourite_restaurant',
                                                  related_query_name='favourite_restaurant')
```

I have defined a serializer for Restaurant model which is mainly :

```
class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now in my ViewSet logic I am doing the following :

```
class RestaurantListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = RestaurantSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = {'Error': 'Please pass valid url parameters'}
        city = self.request.query_params.get('city', None)
        postal_code = self.request.query_params.get('postalcode', None)
        country = self.request.query_params.get('country', None)
        if city is not None or postal_code is not None:
            queryset = Restaurant.objects.filter(
                Q(city=city) | Q(pincode=postal_code))
        if country and city is not None and postal_code is None:
            queryset = Restaurant.objects.filter(country=country, city=city)
        return queryset

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        restaurant_qs = self.get_queryset()
        ids_list = [restaurant.id for restaurant in restaurant_qs]
        favourite_restaurant = is_favourite_restaurant(ids_list, self.request.user)
        serializer = RestaurantSerializer(restaurant_qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

where `is_favourite_restaurant` is a custom function function which returns queryset of FAVOURITE restaurant(s) of a user. Now in the output for this GET request I am getting result as :

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name_of_the_restaurant": "Aniket",
        "opening_time": "14:08:33.413402",
        "closing_time": "22:08:33.413414"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name_of_the_restaurant": "Aniket-1",
        "opening_time": "14:13:37.656385",
        "closing_time": "22:13:37.656397"
    }
]
```

Whereas the desired output I want is to append an extra field `is_favourite:true` to that restaurant which user has previously marked favourite. And hence the output should be

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name_of_the_restaurant": "Aniket",
        "opening_time": "14:08:33.413402",
        "closing_time": "22:08:33.413414",
        "is_favourite": true, 
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name_of_the_restaurant": "Aniket-1",
        "opening_time": "14:13:37.656385",
        "closing_time": "22:13:37.656397"
    }
]
```

EDIT :

Definition of is_favourite_restaurant function :

```
def is_favourite_restaurant(restaurant_qs, user):
    favourite_restaurant_qs = Profile.objects.get(user=user).favourite_restaurant.filter(
        pk__in=restaurant_qs.values_list('id', flat=True))
    return favourite_restaurant_qs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SerializerMethodField. SerializerMethodField allows add extra field which is read only as you want.

```
class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_favorite = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = ('your', 'fields', 'is_favorite')

    def get_is_like(self, obj):
        return is_favourite_restaurant(obj.id, self.context['request'].user)
```

Normally, ListAPIView add context to serializer. As you use your create method, you should add manually.

```
serializer = RestaurantSerializer(restaurant_qs, many=True, context={'request': self.request})
```

Context allows access some data which is we send from the view.

As you did not shown your is_favourite_restaurant, i can't say that  what should you do in that function. I guess you should change ids parameter from array to one id.

Your response looks like

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name_of_the_restaurant": "Aniket",
        "opening_time": "14:08:33.413402",
        "closing_time": "22:08:33.413414",
        "is_favourite": True, 
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name_of_the_restaurant": "Aniket-1",
        "opening_time": "14:13:37.656385",
        "closing_time": "22:13:37.656397",
        "is_favourite": False, 

    }
]

def is_favourite_restaurant(restaurant_id, user):
    favourite_restaurant_qs = Profile.objects.get(user=user).favourite_restaurant.filter(
        pk=restaurant_id).exists()
    return favourite_restaurant_qs
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, if you have got concern about speed, you can read annotation from docs.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate